# libmosquittopp - loop_start() returned error code 10 (0xA)

Tags: mqtt

I'm trying to create my MQTT client(pub/sub) with "MQTTWrapper" class. 
I tested connect_async() and loop_start() functions.
But loop_start() returned error code 10. I think it means "MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED". 
I'm testing MQTT version 2.0.7.
Anyone who can help me?

mqtt_client.h

```
class mqtt_client : public mosqpp::mosquittopp
{
public:
    mqtt_client (const char* id, const char* topic, const char* host, int port, int keepalive, int qos);
    ~mqtt_client();

    void on_connect(int rc);
    void on_disconnect(int rc);

    int afx_connect();
    int afx_disconnect();
    int afx_publish(const char* msg);    
};
```

mqtt_client.cpp

```
int mqtt_client::afx_connect()
{
    int rc = connect_async(host_, port_, keepalive_);
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
        CLog::WriteLog(_T("connect_async() failed. Code %d"), rc);
        return rc;
    }

    //Start a thread and call mosquitto_loop() continuously in the thread to process network information
    rc = loop_start();
    if (rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS) {
        CLog::WriteLog(_T("loop_start() failed. Code %d"), rc);
        return rc;
    }

    return MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what platform are you on?